# Ставится ли запятая в конструкции со словом «даже»?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, однородные-члены, уточнения

*"Мороз выжал влажность из древесных сучьев и стволов, и кусты и деревья, даже
камыши и высокие травы опушились блестящим инеем".*

Вопрос: нужно ли ставить запятую перед словом "опушились"? Ведь я вижу данную конструкцию как уточнение. Даже в оригинале, если я не ошибаюсь, запятая там не стоит...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятую перед *опушились* ставить не нужно.

**Полное предложение** ([Сергей Аксаков. «Очерк зимнего дня»](https://poesias.ru/proza/sergey-aksakov/aksakow10063.shtml)):

> Мороз выжал влажность из древесных сучьев и стволов, и кусты и деревья, даже камыши и высокие травы опушились блестящим инеем, по которому безвредно скользили солнечные лучи, осыпая их только холодным блеском алмазных огней.

[Уточнение](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=118,4) — это переход от более широкого понятия к более узкому. Здесь же *камыши* и *травы* — полноправные подлежащие (это не частный случай *кустов* и *деревьев*). Перед ними стоит [***даже***](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5&all=x) — союз, который соединяет члены предложения, вносит добавление с оттенком усиления.

Comment: Спасибо большое, всё прояснилось!